# Python modules (Jupyter) using wrong anaconda environment on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

My problem is that I am running multiple python environments with different  dependencies on a Windows 10 box. The python themselves are working fine, however when I run Jupyter it does not use the correct python environment.

I have several python environments setup there were installed using

```
conda env create -n python=3.5
```

I installed Jupyter using pip (because the conda install seemed broken at the moment)

```
pip install jupyter
```

I am able to switch between them using activate in the windows cmd

```
>activate env1
/c/Anaconda3/envs/env1/python
>which python
>activate env2
>which python
/c/Anaconda3/envs/env2/python
```

When I run each python binary and check the sys.path it pertains to the correct install.

```
import sys
sys.path

['', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\env1\\lib\\site-packages\\cycler-0.10.0-py3.5.egg']
```

I do not have PYTHONPATH set and the only python entries in my path (other than whatever activate changes) are to the root Anaconda.

```
>echo %PATH%
  ... C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin; C:\Anaconda3\Scripts; C:\Anaconda3 ...
```

Things seem to work well if I am just using python.

However **whenever I try to run jupyter it seems to be using env2 regardless**. In my Jupyter notebook I run the import sys; sys.path and it always seems to point to env2.

I have verified that I am using the correct Jupyter, and I have attempted running Jupyter by calling python.

```
>activate env1
>which jupyter
/c/Anaconda3/envs/env1/Scripts/jupyter
>activate env2
>which jupyter
/c/Anaconda3/envs/env2/Scripts/jupyter

jupyter notebook # This shows env2 in sys.path
python -m jupyter notebook # This shows env2 in sys.path extended by the below entries

'c:\\anaconda3\\envs\\env2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\Users\\username\\.ipython'
```

I have also tried manually installing the correct python in Jupyter and it does not change anything.

```
ipython kernel install --user
```

I have a bunch of dependencies installed in my env1 that my Jupyter notebooks require and I don't want to mess with my env2.

Does anyone have any idea why Jupyter is not using the correct python environment? Is there some python configuration I am not aware of? Is this some odd Windows specific issue?